# Splitting JSON data into 2 groups

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json data  and i want to split into 2 sets of data arrays
One json data will hold all the values under "Construct" data values
and the 2nd json data will hold the rest of the araay and values for product and system.

How do I go about split the JSON into two?

```
{
    "html": [{
        "type": "fieldset",
        "caption": "Construct",
        "html": [{
            "title": "tooltip data for rk",
            "name": "rk_",
            "value": "24",
            "caption": "DNS Servers (a list of IP addresses separated by comas)",
            "type": "textarea"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for rk_ntpservers",
            "name": "rk_ntpservers",
            "value": "111.11.11.11",
            "caption": " separated by comas",
            "type": "textarea"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for ff_eth0_ff",
            "name": "ff_eth0_ff",
            "value": "18",
            "caption": "Public  Address (0.0.0.0 to disable)",
            "type": "text"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for ff_eth0_netmask",
            "name": "ff_eth0_netmask",
            "value": "2.2.2.0",
            "caption": "Public rk Netmask",
            "type": "text"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for ff_eth1_ff",
            "name": "ff_eth1_ff",
            "value": "0.0.0.0",
            "caption": "MG Device rk (0.0.0.0 to disable)",
            "type": "text"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for ff_eth1_netmask",
            "name": "ff_eth1_netmask",
            "value": "2.2.2.0",
            "caption": "MG Device rk Netmask",
            "type": "text"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for ff",
            "name": "ff_gateway",
            "value": "1",
            "caption": "Gateway",
            "type": "text"
        }]
    }, {
        "type": "fieldset",
        "caption": "Product",
        "html": [{
            "title": "tooltip data for product_ident",
            "name": "product_ident",
            "value": "78",
            "caption": "Product Name",
            "type": "text",
            "disabled": "disabled"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for product_svnversion",
            "name": "product_svnversion",
            "value": "7916",
            "caption": "Revision",
            "type": "text",
            "disabled": "disabled"
        }]
    }, {
        "type": "fieldset",
        "caption": "System ",
        "html": [{
            "title": "tooltip data for system_license",
            "name": "system_license",
            "value": "HH",
            "caption": "License",
            "type": "text"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for system_variant",
            "name": "system_variant",
            "value": "normal",
            "caption": "Variant",
            "type": "text"
        }]
    }, {
        "type": "fieldset",
        "class": "btn-fieldset",
        "caption": "",
        "html": [{
            "type": "submit",
            "id": "submitbtn",
            "class": "btn btn-primary",
            "value": "Save"
        }]
    }]
}
```

MY UPDATED CODE now wokring

I cant seem to output the Construct group data  :(. But i can out put the resofJSONdata fine,

```
$(document).ready(function () // don't do anything until the document is loaded.
{

    var baseUrl = "configuration.json";

    $.getJSON(baseUrl, function (data) // call getJSON providing the complete url with search term and a JSONP callback
    {
        // console.log(data.html.splice(2,3));
        // console.log("data " +data);

        console.log(data.html.splice(3, 0)); // remove and log the empty fieldset
        var constructgrp = data.html.shift(); // remove the first item (caption: "Construct")

        var restofJSONdata = data.html;
        alert(constructgrp);

        $("#demo-3-form").empty(); // clear out any previous results.
        if (data.html.length < 1) $('#demo-3-forms').html("No results. Nada. Nuttin. Zippo.");

        //$("#demo-3-form").empty(); // clear out any previous results.
        // if (data.html.length < 1) $('#demo-3-forms').html("No results. Nada. Nuttin. Zippo.");
        //   $.each(this.constructgrp, function () // iterate over the results, constructing the HTML for the display.
        // {

        var html = constructgrp.type + ' :';
        html += '<b>' + constructgrp.caption + '</b><br>';

        html += ' <br>';
        $.each(constructgrp.html, function () {
            //  alert(this.name);
            html += 'Title :' + this.title + '<br>';
            html += 'Name :' + this.name + '<br>';
            html += 'Value :' + this.value + '<br> ';
            html += 'Caption :' + this.caption + '<br><br> ';
            // html += this.type +'<br><br> ';
        });
        $('#demo-3-form').hide().append(html).fadeIn(800); // fade in the results over 2 seconds.
        // });



        $.each(restofJSONdata, function () // iterate over the results, constructing the HTML for the display.
        {

            var html = this.type + ' :';
            html += '<b>' + this.caption + '</b><br>';

            html += ' <br>';
            $.each(this.html, function () {
                //  alert(this.name);
                html += 'Title :' + this.title + '<br>';
                html += 'Name :' + this.name + '<br>';
                html += 'Value :' + this.value + '<br> ';
                html += 'Caption :' + this.caption + '<br><br> ';
                // html += this.type +'<br><br> ';
            });
            $('#demo-3-form').hide().append(html).fadeIn(800); // fade in the results over 2 seconds.
        });


    });
    //});
});
```

html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have confused [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). While the first one extracts array items, the second one removes them. Maybe this is what you want:

```
console.log(data.html.splice(3)); // remove and log the 4th item and everything after 
var constructgrp = data.html.shift(); // remove the first item (caption: "Construct")
var restofJSONdata = data.html; // take what is left over
```

Comment: How do you want to "split" it? The `shift` returns the first element, not an array.

Comment: Thanks .I can ouput the restofJSONdata now,but  I also want to output the constructgrp as well like . restofJSONdata.It doest seem to output anything.

Comment: Just remove the `each` and replace `this` with `constructgrp`. The value is not an array, so no need to loop. Or you'd use `var constructgrp = data.html.splice(0, 1)` to get an array.

Comment: Hey thanks i updated my code, that works now.. have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using JavaScript's [`Array.reduce(...)` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```javascript
var splitData = data.html.reduce(function(memo, x) {
  // Pick the array of "Construct" or "Other" data.
  var arr = memo[(x.caption==='Construct' ? 'Construct' : 'Other')];
  [].push.apply(arr, x.html); // Push to it all of the items in the "html" array.
  return memo;
}, {Construct:[],Other:[]});

splitData.Construct; // => [{value:24,...}, ...]
splitData.Other;     // => [{value:78,...}, ...]
```

Note that if you *only* want the items under "Product" and "System" (and not the other, empty one) then you'll need to add that additional check when picking the target array on which to push the data.

Answer (score 0):

As you only have 3 elements, this seems pretty straightforward:

```
data.html[0] is your Construct
data.html[1] is your Product
data.html[2] is your System
```

So for example an array with Product and System would simply be:

```
[data.html[1],data.html[2]]
```

[Update] If you have more than 3 elements and just need to isolate the first one:

```
var firstElement=data.html.shift();
```

shift() will both remove the first element from the array and return it.

Comment: there is a possibility i could gave 3 or more elements